# MySQL database not reclaiming space

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Im storing base64 strings in one of my table columns in my database which are images that I retrieve - but it's taking up too much space. Hence I created a cron job that basically updates this field to NULL. Where the cron job works, the MySQL database does not seem to reclaiming the space that the base64 consumed.

Any idea as to how I could fix this? Is there an alternative ?

Comment: clone the table or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: Could you elaborate please ? I'm not sure if I follow

Comment: Thanks for that ! The doc states - "Reorganizes the physical storage of table data and associated index data, to reduce storage space and improve I/O efficiency when accessing the table." Reduce Storage space?